# Application State, How long is the data saved in the memory?

Tags: asp.net

How long is the data in a Application State stored ? Untill it's full, or a specific time?
If, until it's full. How much data are we talking about ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State stored in the Application variables will remain there until removed or until the web application recycles or is reset.

As for talking about it being "full" - there is no tracking of how much memory is being used by the `HttpApplicationState` object. One assumes that the process can run into an `OutOfMemoryExcpetion` if you exceed the amount of RAM that can be used by it.

Comment: Ok thank you! 
Can u answear how i can remove a specific Application variable?
Let's say i have one called Application["message1"] and another one called Application["message2"].How do i remove only the application variable named "message1" ?

Comment: @rickard - there is a [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.remove.aspx) method on the Application object.

Comment: Try Remove (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.remove.aspx)

Comment: So logical, thank you guys :) will mark this as answear for my question!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, its stored until you remove it, or the application is recycled.

Consider using the ASP.NET [cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx) instead. You'll have more control over lifetimes.